# Props returning undefined when using redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started learning react-redux and was trying out the same but somehow the props are getting returned as undefined after mapping. Sharing code flow:

Below is the detailed code giving a brief idea on each component used.

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import CakeContainer from './redux/cakes/CakeContainer';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';

function App() {
  
  console.log(store.getState())
  return (  
    <Provider store = {store}>
      
    <div className="App">
     <CakeContainer/>
    </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

CakeContainer.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { buyCake } from './CakeAction'

function CakeContainer(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Cake Container !!</h1>
            <h2>Number of cakes - {props.cake}</h2>
            <button onClick = {props.buyCake}> buy cakes</button>
        </div>
    )
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return {
        cake: state.cakeQuant
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        buyCake: () => dispatch(buyCake())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CakeContainer)
```

Action.js

```
import {BUY_CAKE} from './CakeTypes'

export const buyCake = () =>{
    return{
        type: 'BUY_CAKE'
    } 
}
```

Reducer:
Reducer where i am passing the initial state and action for further processing.

import { BUY_CAKE } from "./CakeTypes";

```
const initialState = {
    cakeQunt : 10
}


const CakeReducer = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'BUY_CAKE': return {
            ...state,
            cakeQunt: state.cakeQunt - 1
        }

        default: return state;
    }
}

export default CakeReducer;
```

Store.js
Creating store and passing reducer details to it

```
[![import { createStore } from "redux"; 


import CakeReducer from './cakes/CakeReducer'
const store = createStore(CakeReducer,window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())

console.log(store.getState())

export default store;][1]][1]
```

Image showing the props value as undefined:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjXU1.png

Comment: Typo. In your reducer it's `cakeQunt` but in `mapStateToProps` you `cake: state.cakeQuant`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese it was totally a miss